# Is GCM production ready? Should we start using it now?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is `GCM` production-ready?

I just wonder if anyone has switched over to it and can report back that it's behaving as advertised. I transitioned from `C2DM` to `GCM` a few days ago in a dev build, but my `GCM` dashboard is still reporting zero data usage which makes me feel not-good. (this is under the Google APIs console, the graph titled `Traffic Reports for [your app name]`). I've been successfully sending messages between dev builds using `GCM`.

It *seems* OK, but I'm hesitant to unleash this on hundreds of thousands of users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's official at C2DM [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) that the service *has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests.*.

According to this I assume that GCM is working now and developers are trully encouraged to migrate from C2DM to GCM.

> "Developers must use GCM for new development."

Comment: Sigh, I still don't see any data coming through in the "Traffic Reports for [app name]" api console. Anyone else seeing data being generated there? My GCM messages are going through ok.

Comment: @user291701, make sure your device's registration ID, sent to your server was obtained by the GCM framework instead of C2DM. As far as I know, a C2DM token is incompatible with GCM and that could be one of the reasons of your traffic data absence.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#stats), it's not supposed to work on the API console :

Viewing statistics

To view statistics and any error messages for your GCM applications:

1. Go to the Android Developer Console.
2. Login with your developer account.
   You will see a page that has a list of all of your apps.
3. Click on the "statistics" link next to the app for which you want to view GCM stats.
   Now you are on the statistics page.
4. Go to the drop-down menu and select the GCM metric you want to view.

**Note: Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM. You must use the Android Developer Console.**